# Как правильно вытягивать данные из RESTful веб сервиса

Tags: rest, uri

Строю RESTful сервис, используя Hibernate.
Имеются страны и города: `Country` и `City`.

Чтобы получить какой-то город я использую URI `http://example.com/countries/{countryId}/cities/{citiId}`

В данном случае я могу из базы данных просто вытянуть город по `cityId`, никак не обращая внимания на `countryId`. А могу сначала вытащить страну по `countryId`, а потом из этой страны вытащить город по `cityId`.

Как правильно делать?

Answer (score 0):

Подробнее, что нужно пользователю ? 
Если просто город и они не повторяются - то первое. Можно подсказку по началу выбора.
Если повторяются - то парами, что бы он конкретезировал выбор. При этом, если в базе связать их по ID то заполнять будет сложнее, но будет всегда связь Город-Страна. Это по моему Оптимально в случае с запросами.
Если нужно страну - то страна, а потом известные города страны. Так меньше ему выбирать. Но связь при этом по ID нужна.

Comment: Логика будет такая: чтобы пользоваться приложением, пользователь сначала должен выбрать страну (будет список стран). Выбрав страну, появится список городов для этой страны, и пользователь должен будет выбрать город. Все города в базе имеют уникальный id, но названия городов могут повторяться. Задачи "найти страну по городу" не стоит.